# Requirements/Guidelines for Writing a Paper

Tags: word-request

What is a word for the requirements/guidelines for writing a paper?

I have to do an essay in which I need to provide a comprehensive definition of such and such, and include explanations for these aspects of such and such, and make sure to explain the significance such and such, and do  lots of other things. All these rules/guidelines are typed onto a single sheet of paper. It's not a rubric or a prompt. What is this piece of paper called?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you provide a sample format or screenshot of one to give us a better idea of what you are looking for? As it is, your question is too broad esp. using *such and such* and *lots of other things*.

Comment: @user3169, the question is clearly stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an [assignment](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/assignment). It can be a homework assignment or a writing assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Different words that have similar applications and when to use them:

A writing **prompt** is usually just a topic given to the writer, like "video games cause violence". A prompt doesn't typically outline all the requirement details. L

The word **assignment** is typically a used for what you described. A set detailed criteria of   particular requirements that must be met to complete something you are ordered to do.

And a **rubric** is typically a standardized format of how something will be graded/judged for quality. Generally one rubric will be used for several different assignments of the same time.